# How to get Uploadify working with Codeigniter + CSRF?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uploadify, csrf

I'm trying to get Uploadify 2.1.4 to work with Codeigniter 2.1.0 and CSRF and I'm not having much luck. I have a very basic upload controller & the following code for uploadify:

```
$(function() {
        var cct = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');
        $('#uploadifyMe').uploadify({
            'uploader'       : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>upload/',
            'cancelImg'      : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'multi'          : true,
            'auto'           : false,
            'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg',
            'fileDesc'       : 'Image Files (JPG, JPEG)',
            'fileDataName' : 'imgData',
            'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
            'simUploadLimit' : 1,
            'sizeLimit'   : 7340032,
            'removeCompleted': false,
            'scriptData' : { 'csrf_token_name' : cct, 'upload' : 'true' },
            'onSelectOnce'  : function(event, data) {
                $('.uploadifyProgress').addClass('progress');
                $('.uploadifyProgressBar').addClass('bar');
            },
            'onComplete' : function(e, i, f, r, d) {
                console.log(r);
            },
            'onError' : function(e, i, f, eO) {
                console.log(eO);
                if(eO.info == 500) {
                    $('#status').prop('class', 'alert alert-error').html('<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><h4>Hmmm. Something gone wrong it has.</h4> Yoda has discovered that your security token has expired. This is because you have been here for longer than two hours. we cannot refresh your key automatically, please refresh the page and try again.');
                }
            }
        });
});
```

The problem is when I upload an image I get a HTTP 500 thrown back at me. I now know it's due to CSRF being turned on since if I turn it off it works fine.

I've tried a load of solutions to the problem. The one you can see in my code, and a one from here that clones your session data and sends it across with the CSRF key, but nothing works. I always end up with a 500 HTTP unless I turn off CSRF.

If anyone can help it would be really appreciated. I realize this question seems to get asked a lot, and it's driving me nutty. On a side note passing the CSRF along with standard AJAX requests works fine, just not with uploadify.

Comment: A small note. While I have CSRF enabled the match user agent option is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code, it enables you to define an array of controller methods that are not subject to CSRF: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/236.

Comment: I realize my accepting the answer is a bit late, but this worked a treat. I've moved to using Laravel for new projects since then which seems to have a much easier to use CSRF system, but this worked great for the clients needs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Uploadify uses a Flash object, which is like a completely different browser, with different session, so the CSRF won't match your session if you POST the cookie data.

You would need to override the original CSRF function with a MY_Security.php file and make so you can get around it by, in example, sending your entire session cookie via POST and make so the CSRF can read it, so you can be matched.

You might as well try HTML5 uploaders like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload that at least gives you a better chance at not having to do such overrides.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I ended up adding an override for the CSRF for the uploadify form. Turns out the client decided against using the system anyway. :(